# Combination of Different Model Classes?

Tags: c#

Recently i accidentally moved from a Dataset World to a Generic World. I am little confused with some of the Model.

In my Model , i had three types of Models as Product { Productid, ProductName},  ProductType {ProductTypeId, ProductTypeName} , ProductCategory {ProductCategoryId, ProductCategorName}

My Stored Procedure  Returns  {ProductName, ProdcutTypeName, ProductCategoryName }

Previously i used to use a Dataset :). But i am worried that how to save these combinations in a List. i cant take List or any other? Do i need to create a seperate class for this?

Could anyone suggest me that how to handle these situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

You should create new models for all combinations your stored procedures return.

If you would start from scratch with, lets say Entity Framework Code First, you would probably define a couple of models that would suite most of your needs and target your custom stored procedures (that would probably be a lot fewer) to those projections.

But now that your are working on an existing database your world will be a bit awkward. And something that can burn you is stored procedures that if/else returns different result sets. Linq frowns on those. I learned this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest You to Create A new Class..Containg ALl the 3 Objects of Previous Classes..that would help you

Comment: is this is the only solution for this..?What if i use 4 Joins in my Stored Procedure .. do i need create another class again?

Comment: Mapping the Classes, could you please suggest me any tutorial on this?

Comment: no i am not using nHibernate or entity framework in my case. I am creating the Models Manually